# Legacy Zope dynamic loading error with MySQL

Tags: python, mysql-python, zope, importerror, python-2.4

I am in the process of moving an old installation of Zope 2 to a new Mac OS 10.8 Server. Unfortunately, our server requires Python 2.4 to run, so I have installed the MacPorts version. The server loads fine until it tries to load the MySQL-python module, at which point it dies with an `ImportError`:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/zope/envLRC/Zope.2.8.6/lib/python/Zope2/Startup/run.py", line 56, in ?
    run()
  File "/home/zope/envLRC/Zope.2.8.6/lib/python/Zope2/Startup/run.py", line 21, in run
    starter.prepare()
  File "/home/zope/envLRC/Zope.2.8.6/lib/python/Zope2/Startup/__init__.py", line 98, in prepare
    self.startZope()
  File "/home/zope/envLRC/Zope.2.8.6/lib/python/Zope2/Startup/__init__.py", line 257, in startZope
    Zope2.startup()
  File "/home/zope/envLRC/Zope.2.8.6/lib/python/Zope2/__init__.py", line 47, in startup
    _startup()
  File "/home/zope/envLRC/Zope.2.8.6/lib/python/Zope2/App/startup.py", line 45, in startup
    OFS.Application.import_products()
  File "/home/zope/envLRC/Zope.2.8.6/lib/python/OFS/Application.py", line 675, in import_products
    import_product(product_dir, product_name, raise_exc=debug_mode)
  File "/home/zope/envLRC/Zope.2.8.6/lib/python/OFS/Application.py", line 698, in import_product
    product=__import__(pname, global_dict, global_dict, silly)
  File "/home/zope/envLRC/Zope.2.8.6/lib/python/Products/ZMySQLDA/__init__.py", line 91, in ?
    import DA
  File "/home/zope/envLRC/Zope.2.8.6/lib/python/Products/ZMySQLDA/DA.py", line 92, in ?
    from db import DB
  File "/home/zope/envLRC/Zope.2.8.6/lib/python/Products/ZMySQLDA/db.py", line 89, in ?
    import _mysql
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.8-x86_64/egg/_mysql.py", line 7, in ?
  File "build/bdist.macosx-10.8-x86_64/egg/_mysql.py", line 6, in __bootstrap__
ImportError: Inappropriate file type for dynamic loading
```

The server is running in a virtualenv to ensure that Python 2.4 is used. Can anyone explain to me why this error is generated and what should be done about it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like something installed/created a `_mysql.py`, you should have a `_mysql.so`. If you have the `.so`, try to rename the `_mysql.py` file and restart.